# Permalink-fu plugin not working for me in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, permalink-fu

I'm using Rails 3 and I've downloaded the [permalink-fu](https://github.com/henrik/permalink_fu) plugin (I've installed and used it in Rails 2.3.8 several times without any issues), but when I go either to the New or Show view of my model (it's called List), I get the following error:

```
undefined method `evaluate_attribute_method' for #<Class:0xb57ede88>
```

This doesn't happen if I remove the `has_permalink :title` line from my `List` model, but I need it in order for the plugin to work.

My model looks like this:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_permalink :title

  def to_param
    permalink
  end
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
  def show
    @list = List.find_by_title(params[:permalink])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @list }
    end
  end

  # GET /lists/new
  # GET /lists/new.xml
  def new
    @list = List.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @list }
    end
  end
```

My routes file looks like this:

```
match '/:permalink' => 'lists#show', :as => :list
```

Could anybody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've made this work by installing the permalink_fu gem instead of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Put into into your gemfile

```
gem "permalink_fu", "~> 1.0.0"
```

then

```
bundle install
```